# How to do a three level for loop

Tags: python

I'm practicing Python programming and now I would like to see an elegant way to do the following: I have a list of 86 rows (a row is a list of 4 elements) of the following form:

```
[[1, 2, 15, 16], [1, 3, 14, 16], ..., [6, 8, 9, 11], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Then how can I find the list of all four 4-element rows such that I can permute the elements of the single row and add them componentwise to make a row [34 34 34 34]?

For example, if I take rows

```
[1,2,15,16], [6,7,10,11], [3,8,9,14], [4,5,12,13]
```

I can sum them to [34 34 34 34] as follows: 1+6+14+13=2+11+9+12=15+7+8+4=16+10+3+5.

I was hoping the output would be 2-dimensional table

```
[[1,2,15,16], [6,7,10,11], [3,8,9,14], [4,5,12,13]]
```

where for example A[0]=[1,2,15,16] and A[0][0]=1. It would output nothing if I can't form a combination of four sums to 34.

What I tried was

```
for a,b,c in itertools.product(range(0,len(row_set)), range(0,len(row_set)),range(0,len(row_set))):
    print(row_set[a],row_set[b],row_set[c])
```

But I'm not sure how can I guarantee that I can permute the lists such that adding components gives always 34.

Comment: you want all sublists that sum to 34 returned?

Comment: Not all of them. The sublists of four 4-lists. For example five 4-list that sum to 34 is not what I'm looking for as it has over four lists.

Comment: Write plain python with for loops and after it works, try to use modules like itertools.

Comment: @user2219896, I think you should add the output you expect to your question.

Comment: `out = filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 34, itertools.product(*row_set))` will give you every possible comination of entries from each sublist that adds up to 34. However, it doesn't choose four sets that only use an entry from each sublist once, which seems to be an additional constraint in your case.

Comment: Your outer loop is most certainly going to look something like `for i in itertools.combinations(row_set, 4):`, which produces the set of all 4-element rows.  I am not sure at the moment how you proceed from there however.

Comment: Is each row composed of numbers in the range 1-16?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this a great deal but it should be close to what you want, no doubt it can be optimised, this is tested on a list of with four sublists.

```
from itertools import product, izip
l = [[1,2,15,16], [6,7,10,11], [3,8,9,14], [4,5,12,13]]
prod = list(product(*l)) # get all possible products of the elements

def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip(*args)
                                     # 4 choices for each list so 4*4*4*4= 256
groups = grouper(prod,len(prod)/ 4)  # group prod in 4 equal groups(len of each sub list)

count = 0
flatten_check = []  # keep list of elements of all products that equal 34
for comb in groups:
    # check if any product is equal to 34 in groups
    check = [c for c in comb if sum(c) == 34]
    flatten_check += [y for x in check for y in x]
    if check:
        count += 1 # if at least one of the products for each comb equals 34 add 1 to  counter
flatten_l = [ x for y in l for x in y] # flatten original list to compare elements

# if each comb had a product that equaled 34, count should equal 4
# if we used all elements in l we satisfied our requirement
if count == 4 and all(item in flatten_check for item in flatten_l):
    print l # print original list
```

For python 3:

```
from itertools import product
prod = list(product(*l)) # get all possible products of the elements

def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args) # izip is gone in python3 as zip now returns an iterator instead of a list

groups = grouper(len(prod)// 4,prod) # group prod in 4 equal groups(len of each sub list)

count = 0
flatten_y = []  # keep list of elements of all products that equal 34
for comb in groups:
    # check if any product is equal to 34 in groups
    check = [c for c in comb if sum(c) == 34]
    flatten_y += [y for x in check for y in x]
    if check:
       count += 1 # if at least one of the products for each comb equals 34 add 1 to counter
flatten_l = [ x for y in l for x in y] # flatten original list to compare elements
# if each comb had a product that equaled 34 count should equal 4
# if we used all elements in l we satisfied our requirement
if count == 4 and all(item in flatten_y for item in flatten_l):
    print (l) # print original list as we have met
```

Comment: Hmm. `ImportError: cannot import name 'izip'`

Comment: @user2219896 are you using python3?

Comment: I used but it seems to work in python2 after inserting coding: utf-8. Thanks!

Comment: @user2219896, No worries, I added code that will work using python3 also. It is probably the 4*4*4*4 that is causing you issues.